# Pandas IndexingError

Tags: python, pandas

I'm following a tutorial about bitcoin and pandas where I'm receiving a data from websocket and storing in a dataframe. Everything is working fine but randomly my script is throwing an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):: 26561.29| MIN: 26530.0 | MAX: 26582.691
  File "/home/user/Desktop/BTC/price.py", line 89, in <module>
    df = df.loc[df.date >= start_time]
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 879, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1090, in _getitem_axis
    return self._getbool_axis(key, axis=axis)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 896, in _getbool_axis
    key = check_bool_indexer(labels, key)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2183, in check_bool_indexer
    "Unalignable boolean Series provided as "
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

This how my code snippet looks like:

```
        df = price['BTCGBP']
        start_time = df.date.iloc[-1] - pd.Timedelta(minutes=5)
        df = df.loc[df.date >= start_time]
        max_price = df.price.max()
```

I think this is related to websocket data because is totally random.

I have changed from 5 minutes to 1 min. and the result of this comparison is:

```
print(df.loc[df.date >= start_time])
                         date     price
0  2021-01-19 18:50:51.724977  27078.59
until
15 2021-01-19 18:51:51.723815  27113.82
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.date >= start_time`

This part is a boolean comparison and returns either `True` or `False`. Try printing the result and you'll see it's a boolean value. However, `df.loc[]`
expects a row number in the form of an integer. What is the intended output for this comparison?

Comment: I've updated my question with the print output